# How can a Material UI Date picker element be triggered from a Flat or Raised button element

Tags: material-ui

I am trying to open the date picker dialog from a Raised button, which is inside a toolbar element, with no joy.

After going through the documentation I found no solution. I tried putting the Date picker inside the Flat Button like so:

```
<RaisedButton label="Start Date" onTouchTap={this.handleRaisedButtonTap} primary={true}>
   <DatePicker autoOk={true} formatDate={this.datePickerFormat} hintText='Start Date' label='Start Date' value={this.state.filter.startDate.display} />
</RaisedButton>
```

I would like to open the date picker dialog when the button is clicked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you have to open it from the refs of the DatePicker component

```
openDatePicker(){
  this.refs.dp.openDialog()
}

render(){
  return (
    <div>
      <RaisedButton onTouchTap={this.openDatePicker} label='open date picker' />
      <DatePicker ref='dp' />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: I had to bind the context to make it work like this onTouchTap={this.openDatePicker.bind(this)}

Comment: @WannyMiarelli If you use ES6 syntax now it is possible to do something like `openDatePicker = () => { ... }` to avoid having to bind, as anonymous functions use their "surrounding" `this` context rather than redefining another one.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore: "Warning: Stateless function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail."

Answer (score 0):

On your onTouchTap event, you can just render the component directly from ReactDOM into a container element (usually a div) thusly:

```
//on TouchTap
handleRaisedButtonTap() {
     ReactDOM.render (<DatePicker ... />, 
             document.getElementById('div datepicker')); 
}
```

It's still just a React component and you can still use the React API on them :)

Comment: This renders an input that, when clicked, opens the DatePicker. I'm guessing he wants the DatePicker dialog to open when he clicks the button.

Answer (score 0):

Open material UI date picker with a button click using useState.

**Example below:**

```
import { MuiPickersUtilsProvider, DatePicker } from "@material-ui/pickers";
const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = React.useState(new Date());
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
  <button onClick={() => setOpen(isOpen => !isOpen)}>Open Picker</button
  <DatePicker onChange={()=> handleDateChange()} open={open} />
</MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```